# Group data with sql or regex

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 1000+ rows in a database where I have data similar this:

```
company_name  - revenue  
123 opel AA   - 100  
234 GForm BB  - 200  
245 opel DF   - 250  
235 Gform BC  - 350
```

I want to summarize the revenue for companies where part of the name is opel and for all where part of the name is Gform so I see:

```
opel - 350   
gform - 550
```

I want to summarize if part of the name will match with part of the name from some other row. I don't know all the names I want to summarize. 
I can, of course, go manually through it but there must be a way to take all parts of the name and match them with part of the company name in any row.

Comment: how many such substrings do you have? and will they always occur at a fixed start and end index?

Comment: Max 8 substrings but most common are 4 substrings. No, they don't start at fixed start or end index. The number, in the beginning, is always fixed size but there can be www. in front of some names and not in front of others.

Comment: Just generate the SQL with `case` statements as below once you get the list of substrings.

Comment: There are more than 1000 rows so I can't get all the substrings easily.

Comment: ...where do the substrings (`opel` and `gform` above) come from? User input?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is **ParseName()**

```
Select Co = parsename(replace(company_name,' ','.'),2)
      ,Revenue = sum(revenue)
 From YourTable
 Group By parsename(replace(company_name,' ','.'),2)
```

Returns

```
Co      Revenue
GForm   550
opel    350
```

Comment: I don't know the names opel and gform - so I can't add them in a like statement.

Comment: @Imageree then remove the WHERE

Comment: @Imageree are you saying that company name can have any pattern

Answer (score 0):

here is one possible way to do this..

```
    ;with mycte as (
select 
'123 opel AA   - 100'   as rawdata
union all
select
'234 GForm BB  - 200 '
union all
select
'245 opel DF   - 250'  
union all
select
'235 Gform BC  - 350'
)
,mycte2 as (
Select
 rawdata

,ltrim(reverse(left(reverse(rawdata),charindex('-',reverse(rawdata))-1))) as quantity

,left(substring(rawdata, 
    charindex(' ', rawdata) + 1, len(rawdata)), 
    charindex(' ', substring(rawdata, charindex(' ', rawdata) + 2, len(rawdata)))) as model

 from mycte
 )

 Select model, sum( cast(quantity as int)) total
 from mycte2

 group by model
```

Comment: the above answer assumes that the row returned is one long piece of string and not separate columns. Once you have the summary, you can then join to the "other" table with the car names (Open etc.,) and restrict the list to only those that you are interested in..

Comment: *Opel.. not Open etc.,

Answer (score 0):

This will perform a fuzzy match, but there are potential pitfalls, but you can tune the logic and/or filters

I should add, if you can't use the UDF, the logic can easily be ported into the CROSS APPLY

```
Declare @YourTable table (company_name varchar(25),revenue int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
('123 opel AA'   , 100  ),
('234 GForm BB'  , 200  ),
('245 opel DF'   , 250  ),
('235 Gform BC'  , 350  )


Select CoName   = RetVal
      ,Revenue  = sum(Revenue)
      ,Records  = count(Distinct Company_Name)
      ,Min_Co   = min(company_name)
      ,Max_Co   = max(company_name)
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](A.Company_Name,' ') B
 Where len(RetVal)>3                      -- significant word lenth
   and try_convert(float,RetVal) is null  -- exlude numeric values
 Group By RetVal
```

Returns

```
CoName  Revenue Records   Min_Co        Max_Co
GForm   550     2         234 GForm BB  235 Gform BC
opel    350     2         123 opel AA   245 opel DF
```

The Parse UDF if needed

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@String,@Delimiter,'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
--Thanks Shnugo for making this XML safe
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('this,is,<test>,for,< & >',',')
```